# Running maven project on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Last week our team decided to move from Netbeans to Eclipse, cause we develop some new plugins that can run only on Eclipse.

At first the project start using my maven plugin from pom `<build>` tag. But the stop doesn't work. In netbeans I used `exec-maven-plugin` to exec, `java -jar Project.jar` from the target folder. Here is the code:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/cp</directory>
    <targetPath>src/cp</targetPath>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/rpt</directory>
    <targetPath>src/rpt</targetPath>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/sql</directory>
    <targetPath>src/sql</targetPath>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>etc</directory>
    <targetPath>etc</targetPath>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>www</directory>
    <targetPath>www</targetPath>
  </resource>
</resources>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>setVersion</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>sh</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>./etc/changeVersion.sh</argument>
          </arguments>
          <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>debugJar</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>cd target/</executable>
          <executable>java</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-Xdebug</argument>
            <argument>-Xnoagent</argument>
            <argument>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</argument>
            <argument>-jar </argument>
            <argument>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</argument>
          </arguments>
          <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>runJar</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>cd target/</executable>
          <executable>java</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-jar </argument>
            <argument>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</argument>
          </arguments>
          <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution></executions>
  </plugin><plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifestEntries>
          <Project-Name>${project.artifactId}</Project-Name>
          <!-- Uncomment if you want to make changes and/or debug in Entuito-->
          <!--<Class-Path>${local.OurFramework.dir}${OurFramework.jar}</Class-Path>-->
        </manifestEntries>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
          <mainClass>${project.groupId}.Mammut</mainClass>
          <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
<extensions>
  <!-- Enabling the use of SSH -->
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

In Netbeans, when we used this build the project had no problem for Debug and Run using Netbeans controls buttons. But in Eclipse the project run and stop button doesn't stop the project. The proccess `java -jar Project.jar` is still running and we must use htop or other methods to kill it. 
Cause of the copying for all of the libs and packaging, are slow proccess and used many read/write operation, we want to Run and Debug the projects using the Java Application run, and to exclude the need of rebuild the whole project for every minor change. But the problem occurs here too. Every project have  dependency that is our java framework and all of the framework resource files are inside the jar archive (some conf.xml files, images and etc.) At most of the time when need to fix our to change something we have both project open in one Workspace. Netbeans and Eclipse automatically detect the dependency  location and change it from .m2 folder to the workspace project that is open at the moment.

The problem here is that when I use `maven clean install` for the framework and then run the main project using JavaApp the project doesn't run cause can't find the resource files from the framework. At this time if I close the frameWork from the workspace and run the main project Eclipse change the dependency path to .m2 folder and everything is fine, but this is very slowly proccess and makes the debug unpossible. 
Can anyone share a pom build that can help me for even one of the problem or any advices and guide "how to" done it properly if my methods are wrong.

Comment: Note that you can switch between Eclipse and Netbeans for Maven projects

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that my Netbeans conf for running the project using maven-exec-plugin is the best way to run it. 
It will be great to not packaging and copy all dependencies for every single change in java code. And that is inpossible if i running it everytime thru java -jar command.

Answer (score 0):

We handled the problem with missing resources when the project and it dependancy is open. Their was a bug in our code for loading the resoure files when they aren't in .jar archive.
 The only thing now that left is this little problem with the Manifest file. There is no manifest file inside project/target/classes/ is there a way to create the same Manifest file like that one from inside the packaged jar.